# Configuration of Istio-Envoy with Consul

Tags: microservices, mesh, consul, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to build a service mesh with Istio. Currently I have a Docker-Compose with two REST-services and one sidecar (Envoy) for each. If you send a HTTP-request to serviceA, it is forwarded to serviceB, which returns the result. It works fine. Because the control plane is not implemented yet, the "mesh" is realized using the Envoy-configuration. The config files look as following:

ServiceA:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
  filter_chains:
  - filters:
    - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
      config:
        codec_type: auto
        stat_prefix: ingress_http
        route_config:
          name: local_route
          virtual_hosts:
          - name: service
            domains:
            - "*"
            routes:
            - match:
                prefix: "/abc"
              route:
                prefix_rewrite: "/v1/abc"
                host_rewrite: serviceB
                cluster: service_ner
        http_filters:
        - name: envoy.router
          config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: service_abc
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: serviceB
        port_value: 80
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

Service B:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
  socket_address:
    address: 0.0.0.0
    port_value: 80
  filter_chains:
  - filters:
    - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
      config:
        codec_type: auto
        stat_prefix: ingress_http
        route_config:
          name: local_route
          virtual_hosts:
          - name: service
            domains:
            - "*"
            routes:
            - match:
                prefix: "/"
              route:
                cluster: local_service
        http_filters:
        - name: envoy.router
          config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: 127.0.0.1
        port_value: 5001
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

Now I want to implement Istio as control plane and I'm trying to replace a part of the configuration using the Istio-Pilot. Is it possible to overwrite the route rules from the Envoy config files by implementing Istio-route rules? For example:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: ruleSerA
spec:
  destination:
    name: serviceA
  precedence: 2
  route:
  - labels:
      version: v1
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: ruleSerB
spec:
  destination:
    name: serviceB
  precedence: 2
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        uri:
          prefix: /abc
  rewrite:
    uri: /v1/abc
  route:
  - labels:
      version: v1
```

What else do I need to configure to connect the data plane with the service plane? Until now the Istio-route rules did not affect the services at all.

Best regards, Martin